# PHP: switch vs if

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

Which form is more efficient

This one:

```
switch($var) {
  case 1:

    break;
  case 2:

    break;
}
```

..or this one:

```
if( $var === 1 ) {

} elseif( $var === 2 ) {

}
```

in terms of performance?

Comment: on performance basis switch case are faster

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and see?

Comment: Let me phrase it this way. The only time you should have a switch statement is if you have more than 1-2 items in an if/elseif block; otherwise using if/elseif is harder to read.

Comment: I can't believe in how fast users actually contribute in StackOverflow.. This is epic!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The performance aspect is completely irrelevant.

As [PHPBench](http://www.phpbench.com/) shows, even with 1,000 operations, the difference between the two is about 188 microseconds, that's 188 *millionths of a second*. PHP code usually has much bigger bottlenecks: a single database call will often take tens of milliseconds, that's tens of thousands of times more.

Use whichever you like, and whichever is better for your code's readability - for many checks, most likely the `switch`.

Comment: +1 for the proof! otherwise -1 :)

Comment: +1 and comparing switch with if is meaning less ... but yes we can terminate if in some case and use switch so that it will be less complex and finely yes its  depends on switchwation

Answer (score 2):

Performance in such micro-scale doesn't matter at all. Use the one which is more suitable in your context. Readability & maintainability is far more important than performance.

Comment: what if he is writing a real time php system?

Comment: Than let the God bless him.

Answer (score 1):

Its not about performance, its more about requirement !!

Sometimes you want something to happen in your if condition, else, it'll go to else.

Switch can be used if you have a lot values to be compared

Comment: And, on top of that, in my opinion a switch is far more readable

Comment: yes, it is, but definitely it depends on requirement, if you have a lot of conditions, then if, and if normal data to select upon then definitely switch

Comment: @user2261839 its not just about php, if and switch work same in all languages